# Convert File to MultiPartFile using Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, file

I have a list of image files wants to convert File object into the MultipartFile object using below code snippet

```
FileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "image/png",
                        false, imageFile.getName(), (int) imageFile.length(), imageFile.getParentFile());
                fileItem.getOutputStream();
                MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
```

**Package: commons-fileupload**

While try to print file size getting as zero ((CommonsMultipartFile) multipartFile).getFileItem().getSize())
So that the file content lenght is store as **0 Bytes**.
Is there any other way to proceed this?

**Note**: I don't want to use MockMultipart file

Comment: JPA is an API for persisting data into a database. You're not persisting data into a database with that question. NOTHING to do with the JPA API

Comment: @BillyFrost But I need to process input parameter as Multipartfile object in my controller class so that I need to convert

Comment: which has nothing to do with the JPA API. If you think you have a problem with JPA then you POST CODE that refers to JPA, with the input and the output from that operation and what you think is a problem